# How can i understand whether the column type is numerical or numerical categorical?

Tags: python, data-analysis, numeric, categorical-data

The dataframe that i am using has columns categorical and numerical. For example ;

```
a       b
1       1
1.35    2
2.42    3
3       3
```

let's think b is numerical categorical column. But sometimes some indexes may be removed. So in this case i need to fill the indexes that have removed. If i know the column is categorical so i will fill the empty column with the previous column's value. So how can i understand the column is categorical or not?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came across this now and I think it should be the first approach:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.types.infer_dtype.html

---

You could check all the unique values that a column holds and decide

```
#List unique values in the df['name'] column
df.name.unique()
```

Pandas does support categorical data type `dtype="category"`

So you could change the type of the column to category for using this knowledge in further calculations

Comment: Ok. But for example we say our b column is categorical. But let's look : df.a.unique() it gives us 1, 1.35, 2.42 and 3 so df.b.unique() gives the same result as well. But how can i understand b is categorical and a is numerical?

Comment: Came across this now - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.types.infer_dtype.html. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

An easy answer is to look at one element of the column via `df.column.iloc[0]`.
Pandas will try to infer the data type of a columns from the data source, once the data type is inferred it will be consistent for every row.